# Cancelled a folder deletion, now it does not appear in the original folder nor the recycle bin

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery

I accidentally clicked on delete on the wrong folder on Windows 8, then I clicked the X in the progress dialog before the deletion was complete, the dialog dissapeared.

Now I don't see the folder in the original path and is not in the recycle bin. This folder is so important that I don't know what to do... where did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download recovery software like Restoration. Then run as Admin. Select the drive C and try to search in results. There is a possibility to find your deleted files.

Comment: Paretologic DataRecovery is a good one? I dowloaded it

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a good answer.